# How to diagnose lambda timeout issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hello I have a lambda function in us-east-1 that faces timeout issues at peak usage times.

The lambda function serves as a handler for multiple functions within an application. The timeout issues are not isolated to a single API within the lambda, and are distributed at random points.

There is a 15s timeout limit that i've configured, but I am wondering why it suddenly starts spiking and does not maintain the typical latency that it experiences during other times of the day.

Here are 2 graphs from a 3 day sample. One of lambda invocations, the other of lambda durations. We can see that the timeouts are correlating with the heavier periods of invocation.

[image]
[image: Err]

I have tried increasing lambda memory & awaiting results.

How can I best diagnose this issue?

Comment: could it be cold start?

Comment: Perhaps you should increase the timeout? You can add some `print()` statements for debugging so that you can review CloudWatch Logs to see what the function was doing when it timed-out.

Comment: I cannot see any correlation between the timeouts - it's happening at different points in the application.

Answer (score 1):

invocation spikes for Lambda functions (or any other cloud service in general) that are in production and exposed to the world is typically timebound for applications with a moderate to large userbase. For example, if the bulk of your userbase lives in an area which follows PST, then expect heavy traffic during the waking hours of PST i.e. 9 am, 12 pm, 6pm, etc.

Note that this is assuming you aren't experiencing a DDoS attack.

However, if your application is private and unexposed, then you might have to examine the patterns of your system in general. Lambda functions are typically event-driven--so to understand the problem, you should take a look at the actual events that trigger your lambda function. You can use Cloudwatch and Cloudtrail to help you gather logs.

You might also want to increase the timeout of your function from 15s to 30s or 1 minute. You might also want to set the amount of concurrency to 0 and use reserved concurrency.

From experience, large invocation volumes in private environments are typically caused by bad architectural design that puts the bulk of the work on the lambda function when in reality it might be better handled by a more robust service such as AWS Glue.

Reference: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-invocation-spike

Comment: Yeah the invocation volume is expected, since the application has more users at certain time frames.

No concerns about DDoS.

Going into logs - the errors are all Timeout, but they are at different points of the application, so cannot find a correlation between them.

Have increased timeout & will look into concurrency. Thanks.

Comment: What does your code do? Is it optimized? What subprocesses does it call?

Comment: It's a backend for an Alexa skill. The code is not optimised.  For subprocesses it calls a few aws services - DDB, Lambda. But not seeing any issues with those.

Comment: That should be fine... Your best bet is to look into the lambda triggers. If you are timing out at different points in the application, it is likely that it's a concurrency issue and not a code issue.

Comment: Unfortunately Alexa skills don't allow you to provision concurrency, since they always have to point to the $LATEST version of the lambda.